# SQLite issues while installing WPF Application

Tags: sqlite

I have .net 4.0 WPF application.My Active Solution platform is "Any CPU" and I'm running on a 64 bit Windows 7 system.I have used Sqlite.It works fine on my system.But when i am installing my application to some other machin,i am getting an error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)" .I've tried compiling for x86 and x64 and I get the same error.Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

as reported in the site of http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

If the development and customer machines may have different processor architectures, more than one binary package may be required. For this situation, using the native library pre-loading feature is highly recommended. It is available as of version 1.0.80.0 and enabled by default. In order to take advantage of this feature, the separate managed and interop assemblies must be used with XCOPY deployment (i.e. this feature is not supported by the mixed-mode assembly, nor when the assembly is deployed to the global assembly cache), resulting in an application deployment that looks something like this:

- \App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly)
- \App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly)
- \System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
- \System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
- \System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional, managed-only EF6 assembly)
- \x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
- \x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)

The string "" above represents the directory where the application binaries are to be deployed on the target machine. With the native library pre-loading feature enabled and the application deployment shown above, the System.Data.SQLite managed-only assembly will attempt to automatically detect the processor architecture of the current process and pre-load the appropriate native library.